# Bash passing input

Tags: shell-script, io

I am using an open source tool to merge files with genomic ranges (Feature to similar to R language function 'merge'). The software can take only two input files at a time. Suppose if I have to merge more than 2 files, I am forced to do this.

```
mytempdata = join  mydata1 + mydata2
mytempdata = join  mytempdata + mydata3
.
.
.
mytempdata = join  mytempdata + mydata(n)
```

I have a separate file containing the path to the files to be merged ( all in different folders). How do I write this in such a way that when I run the command the output of the command is again feed as input.

Comment: What about using pipes? (`command1 | command2` = `command2` take as input the output of `command1`)

Comment: How do you suggest it Dave? Can you explain a bit. Isnt it tedious if I have something like say 50-100 files?

Comment: Tedious manual work = Scripting necessary.
I provided you the basic bone for it: Pipes. 
First of all, does your tool support such redirection? Take a file from the arguments and merge it to whatever comes through the standard input.
If yes, then write a script to loop over the file containing the paths to the files to be merged, concatenating always the output of the previous iteration as input of the current. When you are done with the loop, the final result should be the merge of all files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a simple iterative solution like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
( tmpfile=/tmp/result
  read firstfilename
  cat "$firstfilename" >$tmpfile.in
  while read filename
  do cgatools join \
          --beta \
          --input $tmpfile.in "$filename" \
          --match <specification> \
          --overlap <overlap_spec> \
          --select <output_fields> \
          --always-dump \
          --output-mode compact  >$tmpfile.out
     mv $tmpfile.out $tmpfile.in
  done
) < file_of_filenames
echo "result is in $tmpfile.in"
```

This reads lines (i.e. filenames) one by one from your `file_of_filenames`
and runs `cgatools` using that filename and the previous output, generating a new output file `$tmpfile.out`. This output file is renamed to be 
the input file `$tmpfile.in` and the loop continues.

To handle the start, the first filename line is read separately (into variable `firstfilename`), and that file is copied into the input file so that 
we have 2 files to join. Since all the commands are inside "()" this
ensures the read inside the while loop continues where the first read left off.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your file contains a single file per line, you can do this ugly thing:

```
tool="cgatools join --beta --match <specification> --overlap <overlap_spec> --select <output_fields> --always-dump --output-mode compact --input"

{
    read -r filename
    cmd="cat \"$filename\""
    while read -r filename; do
        cmd+=" | $tool \"$filename\""
    done
} < file_of_filenames

cmd+=" > output_file"

echo "$cmd"
eval "$cmd"
```

The documentation says that if only one input file is given the other file is read from stdin, and if the --output option is not given stdout will be used.

---

untested, but this might work too (bash)

```
# declare the cgatools command with options
# stored in a shell array.
cga_join=( 
    cgatools join --beta 
                  --match "specification"
                  --overlap "overlap_spec" 
                  --select "output_fields"
                  --always-dump 
                  --output-mode compact 
)

# the entry point to the join process
# shift the first argument off the list of arguments, and
# pipe its contents into the recursive call
call_join() {
    local first=$1
    shift
    cat "$first" | call_join_recursively "$@"
}

# recursively call "cgatools join"
# input will be read from stdin; output goes to stdout
# if this is the last filename to join, pipe the output through "cat"
# otherwise pipe it into another call to this function, passing the 
# remaining filenames to join.
call_join_recursively() {
    local file=$1
    shift
    local next_command=(cat)
    if [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; then
        next_command=( "$FUNCNAME" "$@" )
    fi
    "${cga_join[@]}" --input "$file" | "${next_command[@]}"
}

# read the list of filenames to join.
# stored in the "filenames" array 
mapfile -t filenames < file_of_filenames

# launch the joining, passing the filenames as individual arguments.
# store the output into a file.
call_join "${filenames[@]}" > output_file
```

Comment: Thank you Glenn for the thoughtful solution, In this case I have a question. How do I specify the parameters? Should I specify them for a single file or should I provide them normally as I would provide in case of 2 input files.

Comment: I have no idea. I'm not familiar with this tool. Do those specifications have to be different from join to join?

Comment: No glenn, the specifications are the same. only the files should change (passed into the command one by one).